# failure running sparkclr-submit.cmd

Tags: apache-spark, mobius

I am trying to run  a simple spark clr program as local debug mode using VS2012 on my windows environment.

Please find the below steps that i did,

1. Downloaded v1.6.100 from the following page and extracted to my D drive
   https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius/releases

and in my D drive, the folder looks like this,
D:\SparkClr\spark-clr_2.10-1.6.100

2. Set up the following environment variables,

   **SPARK_HOME** = D:\SparkClr\spark-clr_2.10-1.6.100\runtime

   **SPARKCLR_HOME** = D:\SparkClr\spark-clr_2.10-1.6.100\runtime

   **JAVA_HOME** = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92

   **HADOOP_HOME** = D:\HadoopDirectory (winutils.exe is present in D:\HadoopDirectory\bin)
3. Downloaded sparkclr nuget package

In order to set "CSharpBackendPortNumber" in app.config in my local VS program, I need to run in debug mode as per, https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius/blob/master/notes/running-mobius-app.md#debug-mode

but when i run 'sparkclr-submit.cmd debug' from D:\SparkClr\spark-clr_2.10-1.6.100\runtime\scripts

I am getting the following exception,

```
D:\SparkClr\spark-clr_2.10-1.6.100\runtime\scripts>sparkclr-submit.cmd debug
'"D:\SparkClr\spark-clr_2.10-1.6.100\runtime\bin\load-spark-env.cmd"' is not rec
ognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
SPARKCLR_JAR=spark-clr_2.10-1.6.100.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Seq
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.csharp.CSharpRunner.main(CSharpRunner.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.Seq
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

Could you please tell me whether i am missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SPARK_HOME` environment variable should point to Spark directory. You have it pointing to Mobius directory.

Comment: @karthickvas, if it worked, please accept the answer as solution.